# To ignore some files in backup of 16.04?

Tags: backup, 16.04, deja-dup, systemback

I have some data files of several GBs which I would not like to be included in backups. 
I am using at the moment Deja Dup but later Systemback. 
Systemback is making exact mirror images of the system. 
I can prevent files from desktop search by the suffix *.noindex* in OSX. 
Something similar to prevent backups like *.nobackup* would be great. 
It would be great to have some sort of blacklist/ignoreList for some specific filenames.

How can you ignore files from backup by the two backup systems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not recommend to use Deja-dup because it will fail if multiple file-systems and also in many dynamic situations. Just use `tar czf` for making the backup as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/788272/25388) with an attempt for quality assurance. In `tar`, use `--exclude=$HOME/Music/` etc. Make cron if you need regular backup.